# Google Calendar is installed, How do I open it?

Tags: google-calendar

I have recently purchased a Spice MI 350 Handset which is loaded with Android 2.3.3, the phone also has some preinstalled apps.. When I go to application manager -> installed I see Google calendar there but I don't know from where I can open it.. I have tried almost all the options.

I have tried finding "Google Calendar" at android market place but there is no such app (or at least I couldn't find one)... I need a calendar which gets sync with my Google Calendar account..

Since the phone is not rooted I can neither open nor use nor re install it from the market (disappointing) ..How do I get Google Calendar working for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it's called Calendar. Ask your provider if it still isn't showing on your phone.

Alternatively, trying seeing if long-pressing an empty area of your screen and then choosing Widgets - shows the Calendar Widget in the list.

I am assuming of course, that you've already set up your Google Account to sync with your device.

Comment: I tried long pressing the home screen... Unfortunately calendar option is not present in the add widget section... However Google calendar app is visible in the installed section of Application manager...

Comment: Try using an alternative app like Jorte.

Comment: I asked the Customer care of Spice mobiles. They say it is already their. After trying few times I finally started using "Business Calendar" app it is good and automatically synchronizes with my Google account.

Answer (score 1):

Does the app here work for you?
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1317804&page=9

Comment: I have downloaded the .apk file provided there... will it be safe to install it in phone.... How can I verify it is not a spam ?

Comment: It will be safe. It's not spam, because it's been verified by users in XDA forum.

Comment: I tried copying that in the downloads folder of SD card... and since than the phone is showing msg "Preparing SD Card" and notification "Checking SD card for errors...", what to do nxt..? is everything messed up now ? If there is almost a 1GB data how much time it will take to check...? reply fast..

Comment: Have you copied the file to the phone already? Did you install it?